# Maximum size of QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I am using Qt 5.9 on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit architecture. I had a requirement in which I need to take input from a file which can have characters in the range of 10^8. Unfortunately breaking down the file in parts and working on that is not an option as I need the entire data in the file for the operation of my code.

From what I have thought out so far I plan to store the file data in a `QString`(any other suggestions are welcome). What is the maximum size that QString can store in this regard? I have seen the following links but none of them provide a concrete answer:

- [Link 1](https://forum.qt.io/topic/10302/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-string-that-qstring-object-can-hold/6)
- [Link 2](http://markmail.org/message/l3rhabj5hb463xwd)

Since my data falls very close to the limits defined in [Link 1](https://forum.qt.io/topic/10302/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-string-that-qstring-object-can-hold/6) of 2^30, is `QString` a suitable choice for this?

**Note**: All the data will be hexadecimal and I will need to convert the `QString` to a `QByteArray` down the line.

My other concern is if it will be able to handle that many number of characters efficiently. From what I have [read](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#capacity) Qt optimizes the string length as **a means of fine tuning QString's memory usage**. Will this impact the file read operation considering the huge amount of characters(in terms of time taken).

Adding a sample code for read operation:

```
void readData (QString file) {
    QFile f(file);
    if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) break;
    QTextStream in(&f);
    QString data=in.readAll(); // alternately, this can be read line by line along with QStringBuilder
}
```

Comment: Nobody puts that much text in a single string. Large texts are stored in text documents, where they are much coarsely grained and much more efficient to edit.

Comment: @dtech Like I said I need the entire data in the file for a single write operation(to a serial port). I don't need to edit the file or its contents in any way. Also if not Qstring is there any other data structure that can handle this much data?

Comment: Reads the entire content of the stream, and returns it as a QString. Avoid this function when working on large files, as it will consume a significant amount of memory. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#readAll       --- read line by line `QString QTextStream::readLine(qint64 maxlen = 0)`

Comment: yes read that. Read the comment next to the same line of code. Have just provided the code to give a general idea.

Comment: You don't need to load the whole thing into memory. Serial ports are very low bandwidth, so you can safely read small chunks and send through one chunk at a time. You don't gain anything from reading it into memory. It is inefficient and extremely amateurish. You need like a few bytes of memory to do that, not megabytes.

Comment: @dtech so adding simultaneous reads(from file) and writes(to port) wont give any delays? Also, the file size I mentioned is for the extreme case, in general, it will be much lesser size. So based on that I wanted to write the entire thing in one go as I would do for smaller file sizes

Comment: You can use double buffering, stream from buffer A while filling buffer B then switch, seamlessly transitioning between the two. Buffers will be very fast to fill, since hard drives are much much faster than serial ports. But even without double buffering you will probably be fine for a serial port.

Comment: Use `QBuffer` for reading data from file and provide it as a data source for your serial port

Comment: Are you using [`QSerialPort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html)? You don't need to write everything in one call.