# Append a Very Big String

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

When I try to add a big QString (size:104806123) to a QPlainTextEdit I get an exception :C++: std::bad_alloc

```
void LogFileialog::add(QString &logLine)
{
    ui.log_plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(logLine);
}
```

I also tried to append the Text to the QPlainTextEdit splitting the data in many QStrings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blockNumber; i++) 
    ui.log_plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(logLine[i]);
```

but around at 570.000 row iI get the std::bad_alloc.
The problem not is in QString, but when I call appendPlainText(QString)

There is a better way to add a Big String to a QPlainTextEdit ?

Comment: Clearly, appending a string involves dynamic memory allocation, which is more likely to fail if allocating a large amount of memory.   If there is insufficient memory available and the allocation fails,  there isn't a great deal that can be done - other than, maybe (at best), releasing other dynamically allocated memory and trying again.     I suggest you redesign your program to avoid needing such a large string, let alone trying to append it.

Comment: Generally it is easier to allocate many small blocks of memory than a single large one. See if you can split the data.

Comment: QString has a limit to its size. I found out the hard way when dealing with 500+ MB xml files in Qt in 64 bit code.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/10302/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-string-that-qstring-object-can-hold/4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237476/maximum-size-of-qstring

Comment: I also tried to append the "logLine" by splitting in blocks :
`for (int i = 0; i < blockNumber; i++)
        ui.log_plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(logLine[i]);`
but around at 570.000 row i get the std::bad_alloc.
The problem not is in QString, but when I call **appendPlainText(QString)**

Comment: Because of my three comments I don't think this will work at all regardless of how you attempt. you just have too much data for classes that use `QString` because of the `QString` size limitation. `QPlainTextEdit` likely stores the text in a `QString`.

Comment: Note that QByteArray does not have the same limitation

Comment: Ok, as I wrote, I splitted in many QString (1000 char for each String).
Now, if I try to add the many QString(s) to QPlainTextEdit, i get the exception around at 570.000 row.

Comment: Understood, I expect that to happen.

Comment: Using Qt at 64bit I extended the limit. Now I Can add more than 570.000 rows. I don't know the appendPlainText() 64 bit limit.